Extracting non-standard evaluation scores from PGN comments using python-chess
I have a PGN file, which is an output of Cute Chess.
1. e4 {+0.42/27 1.6s} e5 {-0.21/26 5.4s} 
2. Nf3 {+0.34/22 0.94s} Nc6 {-0.16/19 0.37s} 
3. Bb5 {+0.35/27 2.1s} Nf6 {-0.19/26 0.80s}
4. O-O {+0.33/22 0.56s} Nxe4 {-0.16/26 0.92s} 
5. Re1 {+0.29/27 1.0s} Nd6 {-0.19/24 0.66s} 
6. Nxe5 {+0.32/24 0.59s, No result} *

I want to write a Python program to read it. My code is as follows:
self.move_stack = []

with open(file_path) as f:
    game = chess.pgn.read_game(f)
    if game:
        self.board = game.board()
        self.move_stack = list(game.mainline_moves())

It can extract moves, but I don't know how to extract the scores like 0.42.
I have read the documentation about parsing PGN files. It says GameNode.eval() should work. But I tried game.eval() and game.variations[0].eval(), both of them didn't work.
game.variations[0].comment returns the whole comment "+0.42/27 1.6s". I just want the first part 0.42.
Finally, I managed to use a crude method to get the scores:
i=0
for x in move_comment:
    if x!= "/":
        i=i+1
    else:
        break
original_score=move_comment[0:i]   
The_original_scores.append(float(original_score))

There must be a simpler way to do it.

An ad-hoc solution is score, depth = game_node.comment.split()[0].split('/'), where score may require additional cleanup, e.g. score = score.replace('M', '') with a notification stored somewhere that it's not a centi-pawn but mate score at the moment (CuteChess is deciding dynamically which one to use).

Thank you. Actually, the bug showed up.  I just checked if  score[1]=='M', replace it with 10.

The chess.pgn uses regular expression to get the move lines. You can see MOVETEXT_REGEX and other compiled patterns in the source code. And it gets all the text between the curly brackets as comments.
You can also use regular expression to get the comments, or just part of it, from the move lines. But since you already have the whole comment it's simpler just to split it.
original_score = move_comment.split("/")[0]
The_original_scores.append(float(original_score))  # use float(original_score[1:]) to remove the +/- signs

Doing the same using regular expression
import re

pattern = r"[+|-](\d+\.\d+)/"
match = re.search(pattern, move_comment) 
if match != None:
    original_score = match.group(1)
    The_original_scores.append(float(original_score))


You've already figured out how to get the move comments.  Any Python string can be split using the "split" function.  In this case, you want to split the string at the "/" character.  Like this:
s = "+0.42/27 1.6s"
x = s.split("/")  # x is now a list of strings, with the "/" removed
for a in x:
    print(a)  # Each a is a string

# The first element of x is the one you want, x[0]
# It's a string, but You can convert it to a floating point number
print(float(x[0]))

Output:
+0.42
27 1.6s
0.42


python-chess 1.11.1
python-chess can extract data from comments, such as score evaluations or elapsed move time, but only if they follow a specific syntax (see the PGN Specification Guide for reference).
Score evaluations are detected in the comments using the "[%eval ...]" pattern. They can appear as either "[%eval #±12,34]", representing mate scores, or "[%eval ±12.34,56]", representing centi-pawn scores. The value after the comma indicates the evaluation depth, which can be extracted using GameNode.eval_depth.
These data are extracted by re module. The exact extraction pattern can be found in chess.pgn.EVAL_REGEX.pattern:
print(chess.pgn.EVAL_REGEX.pattern)

#    (?P<prefix>\s?)
#    \[%eval\s(?:
#        \#(?P<mate>[+-]?\d+)
#        |(?P<cp>[+-]?(?:\d{0,10}\.\d{1,2}|\d{1,10}\.?))
#    )(?:
#        ,(?P<depth>\d+)
#    )?\]
#    (?P<suffix>\s?)

In case of the provided data, there's no "[%eval ...]" in comments, so GameNode.eval method returns None. But we can adjust EVAL_REGEX to match the obvious pattern in those comments:
import chess.pgn
import re

chess.pgn.EVAL_REGEX = re.compile(r"""
     (?P<prefix>\s?)
     (?:
         \#(?P<mate>[+-]?\d+)
         |(?P<cp>[+-]?(?:\d{0,10}\.\d{1,2}|\d{1,10}\.?))
     )(?:
         /(?P<depth>\d+)
     )?
     (?P<suffix>\s?)
     """, re.VERBOSE)

With this matching pattern, we can use game_node.eval() or game_node.eval_depth() as described in the documentations.
For more complex or varied formats, we may need to implement our own parser. For example, to extract emt in this case, we can't just change EMT_REGEX without further modifying the library code, as Cute Chess does not provide hours and minutes like in [%emt h:mm:ss.ms]. Additionally, Cute Chess represents mate scores as "±M42", with 'M' separating the sign and the number. This makes it difficult to address the issue simply by substituting a regular expression.
cutechess_regex = re.compile(r'''
    (?:(?P<mate>[+-]?M\d+)|(?P<cp>[+-]?\d+\.\d+))
    (?:/(?P<depth>\d+))?
    \s+(?P<emt>\d+.\d+)s
    ''', re.VERBOSE)

def parse_comment(game_node):
    from chess.engine import PovScore, Cp, Mate
    from collections import namedtuple
    NodeEval = namedtuple('NodeEval', 'score depth emt')
    match = cutechess_regex.search(game_node.comment)
    if match is None:
        return
    mate, cp, depth, emt = match.groups()
    turn = game_node.turn()
    if mate:
        score = Mate(int(mate.replace('M', '')))
    else:
        score = Cp(round(float(cp) * 100))
    score = PovScore(score if turn or mate == 0 else -score, turn)
    if depth: 
        depth = int(depth)
    if emt: 
        emt = float(emt)
    return NodeEval(score, depth, emt)

Now we can update the game comments to meet the expectations of both programs.
step = game.next()
while step:
    data = parse_comment(step)
    if data:
        step.set_eval(data.score, data.depth)
        step.set_emt(data.emt)
    step = step.next()

first_step = game.next()
print(f'{first_step.comment = }',
      f'{first_step.eval() = }',
      f'{first_step.eval().relative.score() = }',
      sep='\n')

# first_step.comment = '+0.42/27 1.6s [%eval 0.42,27] [%emt 0:00:01.6]'
# first_step.eval() = PovScore(Cp(-42), BLACK)
# first_step.eval().relative.score() = -42


Thanks for your reply. It is my mistake. I didn't mention the PGN is read from a ***.pgn file. Though I don't use StringIO, just         with open(file_path) as f:             game = chess.pgn.read_game(f), and then  first_move = game.next() print(f'{first_move.eval() = }',       f'{first_move.eval_depth() = }',       sep='\n').  It just print first_move.eval() = None first_move.eval_depth() = None first_move.emt() = None

Thanks. The pgn file is output of Cute Chess. I want to write a python program to read it.   Now I am using split function.

yes, I noticed that. Thank you.
